# Блокировка курсора в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как заблокировать положение курсора в unity

пробовал `Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;` но данный вариант не подходит тк курсор оказывается в центе

Как ещё можно реализовать блокировку курсора так, чтоб после разблокировки курсор оказывался в том месте, где и был заблокирован?

Comment: Запоминайте координаты перед блокировкой и востанавливайте в них. Либо можете вообще не блокировать, а делать курсор невидимым, если такой вариант подойдет.

Comment: Если пишете под Windows, то есть [вот такое решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59330887/12888024)

Comment: Сохранение и запись положения курсора очень плохой вариант тк запись это абсолютный метод, а им пользоваться нежелательно